# inputSelect returning value to parent component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have the following component, right now when I change the inputSelect `selectedValue` is changing correct and I can see it changing in the `console.log`

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="pickListTitle" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="style_class" type="String" description="Style class 
 for div"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
<!-- "{!v.style_class}" -->
<div>
    <ui:inputSelect label="{!v.pickListTitle}" class="dynamic" aura:id="optionItems" change="{!c.onChange}" value="{!v.selectedValue}"/>
</div>
```

My goal is that I want to be able to see it in my top level component, I want  to make one generic pick list that can handle any `List` of strings because I don't want to build this each any every time, how would I go about getting this value in my parent component?

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <c:Tabs type="scoped">
         <c:Tab title="Item One">
            Test
            <c:Picklist pickListTitle="Picklist title" options="['Test 1','Test 2','Test 3']" pxWidth="15"/>
            <!-- Is it possible to return the value up? -->
        </c:Tab>
        <c:Tab title="Item One">
            Hello 1
        </c:Tab>
        <c:Tab title="Item Three">
            Hello 2
        </c:Tab>  
        <c:Tab title="Item Four">
        </c:Tab> 
    </c:Tabs>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: You can fire a custom event when your `inputSelect` value is changed and handle it in your parent component. As you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_example.htm).

Comment: You can also pass in an attribute from the parent to the child and use that in the value of the select. then when changed in the child it is automatically propogated

Comment: @Eric I ended up doing what you said, I didn't see a reason to fire an event for a picklist value.  I'd imagine a picklist wouldn't control any other components in my case

Comment: @EricSSH - All depends on your use case. I have also had issues passing values from classes etc but individual attributes usually work well. It generally works and when it does not there are ways to make it work lol. I'll add the comment as an answer so you can accept if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an attribute from the parent to the child and use that in the value of the select.

When changed in the child it is automatically propagated to the parent attribute